# How do I make calculation on a custom Epoch time? Not the UNIX epoch

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, epoch

I am receiving data from a server in **seconds** and I want to convert it to date.

But the seconds I am receiving is not since the UNIX epoch 01/01/1970 but is 01/01/2000.

Normally I'd use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(millisToConvert));
```

Where millisConvert is converted-to-milliseconds seconds that I receive. But now, naturally, I get wrong dates since the origin is different. How do I change the epoch (the origin) ?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 2000 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Define your epoch reference moment. 
.pluSeconds( yourSeconds )  // Add the number of seconds given to you. Returns another `OffsetDateTime` object rather than altering the original (immutable objects pattern).  
.toLocalDate()     // Extract a date-only value without time-of-day and without offset-from-UTC.
```

## *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment in UTC.

Define your particular epoch reference date-time.

```
Instant epoch = Instant.parse( "2000-01-01T00:00Z" ) ;
```

Add your number of seconds.

```
Instant later = epoch.plusSeconds( yourSecondsGoHere ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

If you want a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class. First, convert from the basic type `Instant` to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime`, specifying the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` as the offset.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

Extract the date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: That's a great answer. I was really started to think that it was not possible so that I have to try find a way to add 30 years to a date. But very very important question here is, the methods you share here is only available in Android API 26 or newer, which is so so new. Any other way you can think of for lower API's for support? It can be long I do not mind as long as it works.

Comment: @bengongon97 See *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 1):

Add 946080000 seconds to account for the 30 year difference, epoch time should be an long value

Comment: Add or subtract as needed but also multiply/divide by 1000 to convert millis <-> seconds

Comment: Thanks for both comments but I already tried it. The reason I cannot do that is that method creates integer overflow. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using an int or a long? Date takes a long value and we are nowhere near that value in ms

Comment: I use long. How that will help us? I dont understand.

Comment: An integer can store `2^32`, long can store `2^64`. If you're getting an INTEGER overflow then that means the value you're trying to store is larger than 2^32 (ie. 2.147 billion), so you need to use a long, whos value we have not yet exceeded in epoch time

Answer (score 0):

Another way apart from what Basil suggested as I marked as an answer. What Basil suggests works only on API level 26 and higher meaning Android 8.0.0. Nowadays, post-mid 2018, Android 8.0.0 is pretty rare so many devices will not have this functionality.

So I wrote this algorithm:

```
private long getDateInMilliSeconds (long secondsSinceRippleEpoch){

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) { //**WHAT BASIL SUGGESTED**
            LocalDateTime desiredDate = OffsetDateTime.of(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .plusSeconds(secondsSinceRippleEpoch)
                    .toLocalDateTime();

            Date convertedDate = Date.from(desiredDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

            return convertedDate.getTime();
        } else { //MY SOLUTION. Works for both but still I wanted to use the upper
//for higher APIs.

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date((secondsSinceRippleEpoch+946684800)*1000L )); //To not to cause overflow, use L at the end.

            try {
                Date wantedDate = formatter.parse(dateString);
                return wantedDate.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 200000;
            }

        }
```

Hope this helps the future visitors.

Comment: No need to ever use the troublesome legacy date-time classes. Always use *java.time* classes. For Java 6 & 7 and early Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Comment: What makes them troublesome? Why everybody say that? It is because localization errors? Or conversion?

Comment: There are many poor design decisions in the legacy classes. Search to learn more. No point in getting into it now. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310.